# DSP, Related Math, Statistics, and Jitter Primers

Tags: statistics

I'm a CS who took an internship at an EE shop, and I'm trying to do some work developing in house and client applications for a chip designer, and I'm having some fundamental communication problems. Mainly I shore up any applications they need developed from their specs, including at the moment a tool that demonstrates Jitter on a given PLL. I've had some high level stats, linear algebra, and DIP courses that I thought would have prepared me for this, but right now I've got a 50 pages on how to calculate Peak to Peak Jitter, Period Jitter, Random Jitter, and Long Term Jitter, and I can't seem to get a solid equation/algorithm out of any of it. It seems to approach RMS like it's a constant number.

I'm not sure what I need to tackle this. Does any one have a(some) primer(s) on the subject(s)?

Comment: RMS *is* a single number for a given set of samples